# Moving order of tags via Regex

Tags: regex

I have a document with

```
<relation>
<relationType>USE</relationType>
<termName>a name</termName>
<termId>an ID</termId>
</relation>
```

The system we use needs

```
<relation>
<termId>an ID</termId>
<termName>a name</termName>
<relationType>USE</relationType>
</relation>
```

Is it possible to write a regex to reorder these properties?  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Trying to manipulate XML using regexes will lead to [madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) instead.

But I can't see how the order should matter. That's what using named key/value pairs does for you. If the document consumer requires them in a particular order it's broken.

Comment: its leading to maddness alright!  Thanks a lot I'll take a look at that, and try to master the command line.  The consumer needs them in a format which apparently is strict about order of tags in <relation>, thanks again, Charlie